# Link causing top of page jump

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

UPDATE: I've found another js file that was interfering. Many thanks for all the replies.

I'm using the code below to toggle an accordion menu, though each time a `.menu li.sub` is clicked, the page jumps to the top... I've tried placing `return false` all over the place, but I can't seem to get it to work..

Here's the code; many thanks:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery('.menu ul').slideUp(0);

    jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function () {
        var target = jQuery(this).children('a');
        if(target.hasClass('menu-expanded')){
            target.removeClass('menu-expanded');
        }else{
            jQuery('.menu-item > a').removeClass('menu-expanded');
            target.addClass('menu-expanded');
        }
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first')
                    .slideToggle(350)
                    .end()
                    .siblings('li')
                    .find('ul')
                    .slideUp(350);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try using event.preventDefault() in click callback.

Comment: Do you have a `href="#"` in the link tag?

Comment: The links that jump have href="#", yes.

Comment: @Rain, any of the answers given should have solved the problem.  See [this example](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/FbLsw).  Open the page in Chrome, click one of those links, and then press F12.  Click console, and copy all of the text there into your question, please.

Comment: I know they should've, yet they don't :(

Comment: Here's a test site (http://thatblognetwork.com/wp34/) and here's the *.js: http://thatblognetwork.com/wp34/wp-content/themes/Touch/js/accordion.js

Answer (score 0):

Use a return false at the end of the click event handler:

```
jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function () {
    var target = jQuery(this).children('a');
    if(target.hasClass('menu-expanded')){
        target.removeClass('menu-expanded');
    }else{
        jQuery('.menu-item > a').removeClass('menu-expanded');
        target.addClass('menu-expanded');
    }
    jQuery(this).find('ul:first')
                .slideToggle(350)
                .end()
                .siblings('li')
                .find('ul')
                .slideUp(350);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're invoking a click event to an li element "jQuery('.menu li.sub').click"

Why not target the anchor tags (links) like this: jQuery('.menu li.sub a')

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**event.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
 jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function (e) {

      //Your code
    e.preventDefault(); 
    }
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't do it either.

Comment: you forget to add event parameter, `jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function (e) `

Comment: Also try `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: These don't appear to do it either.

Comment: `jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      //Your code    
    }` try changing like this.

Comment: @Rain can be specific.  which one?  possible post a fiddle.  I don't find any class named `.menu`